# Calculate average date in PostgreSQL db

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL which has orders purchased at various dates. In order to archive the data we need to merge all the records of the year and merge it into one record with a average purchase date calculated based on the purchase dates.

How do I calculate the average purchase date in PostgreSQL? Or Is there a way to do it in JAVA?

Comment: Ohh man !! Please provide the table details(DDL and sample data),Show input values as well as expected output

Comment: What is the "average purchase _date_"? The term "average" does not make sense with dates. I have no idea what the equivalent to `(1+2+3+4+5) / 5` for dates should be, because ` 2015-09-1 + 2015-09-07 + 2015-09-20` doesn't make sense

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'd agree that this is a rather odd accounting practice but dates within a single year are just integers in the `[1,365]` interval (or `[1,366]` in a leap year) and those can be averaged. Averaging arbitrary dates (i.e. not all in the same year) would also be possible if you chose a suitable interval to covered them all.

Comment: It's more typically useful to generate seasonally-adjusted averages of sales by date, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should convert your dates to an `epoch` (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00), take the average of that, then turn the result back into a date:

```
SELECT extract(year from purchase_date) AS year_of_purchase,
       to_timestamp(avg(extract(epoch from purchase_date)))::date AS avg_purchase_date
FROM orders
GROUP BY 1;
```

Add other fields and filters as required.

Comment: really creative workaround to a limitation that should've been implemented 7 years later

Answer (score 3):

Since your dates are all in the same year, you could use [`extract`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) to convert the dates to a day-of-year, average those numbers, and then add that back to the first day of the year to get a date:

```
select '2015-01-01'::date
     + avg(extract(doy from whatever_your_date_column_is))::int
     - 1
from ...
```

You need the `::int` cast because `avg` gives you a double precision value but there is no operator for adding doubles to dates; the `-1` adjustment is needed because the day-of-year values are one-based rather than zero-based. Note that [adding an integer to a date](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE) simply adds that many days.

You would, of course, adjust the `'2015-01-01'` to match whatever year you're working with.

Answer (score -1):

## java.time

In [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), if you want the average date within a timeframe of the calendar year you could use the `ZonedDateTime` class and it's [`getDayOfYear`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#getDayOfYear--) method.

For a timeframe beyond the calendar year, you could choose a point in the past. I suggest the Java epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC. See the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`. Search StackOverflow to learn how to get the number of days from that early pint to each of your date-time instances. Average those numbers of days to arrive at your average date.